# Is compilation different for each targeted .NET Platform?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, clr, .net-core

In .NET we have several platforms each of which is composed by its own runtime, its own base libraries and its own supporting software for booting the runtime and so forth.

Concerning those different platforms we can *target a specific platform when we are compiling our code*. This means that we compile *for a specific platform*.

In the new .NET Core project model this is even clearer. On the `project.json` file we specify in the `frameworks` section the platforms we want to compile for by listing their TFM's.

My problem here is that as I understand, the main difference between developing to a platform or another is the base libraries available (for the full .NET we have the whole BCL for instance). But this seems to be one "run time issue" rather than "compile time issue".

The reason is that when the code is deployed as IL to the specific platform and when it's going to run that it'll see if the necessary assemblies from the needed base libraries are available right?

In that case, why there's this idea of "compiling for a specific platform"? Is the compilation process different for each platform? Is the generated IL different for each platform?

Comment: The generated IL [stays the same](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2012/04/04/what-anycpu-really-means-as-of-net-45-and-visual-studio-11/) with only a flag to decide what happen when the app is run (translate the IL to x86 machine code on x64 OS, etc)

Comment: The whole *point* of having IL in the first place is that it's not platform specific, and that any compliant runtime *must* be able to run it (by definition; if it couldn't, then it wouldn't be a compliant runtime).

Comment: That's exactly my doubt, since the IL is not platform specific and any compliant runtime must be able to run it, why do we need to target a specific platform when building? The differences between platforms aren't just at run time? I don't get why compilation shouldn't be the same.

Answer (score 1):

> In that case, why there's this idea of "compiling for a specific platform"? Is the compilation process different for each platform? Is the generated IL different for each platform?

The IL is different, but generally only slightly, i.e. the assembly flags may be different, to indicate the target platform specified when compiled.

Of course, you may have conditionally-compiled code in your assembly, protected by `#if` directives. I assume you are not referring to that sort of difference. But just because the main part of the IL is the same from platform to platform, that doesn't necessarily mean you can run any IL on any platform.

Often, the target platform specified during compilation will be a critical choice, because the managed code engages in some kind of interop with native code that's available only for a specific architecture. Another reason is if the program for some reason *requires* the use of x64 architecture for virtual address space reasons (i.e. the process expects to need to allocate more than the nominal 3GB maximum available to x86 processes).